# Alternative to imakeidx with Overleaf/PDFLaTex

Tags: indexing, pdflatex, overleaf

What is the alternative of imakeidx with Overleaf/PDFLatex to produce indexes having the following requirements:

1. Nested: Beging able to have up to 5 levels (imakeidx is limited to 3)
2. No. of Indexes: Being able to have at least 5 indexes (imakeid is limited to 5)
3. Order of the Elements in the Indexes: Specify the order of the elements of a given level i.e. being able to recognise @ in newcommand
4. Hyperlink: Being able to click on the page number on the index to access to it
5. TOC: Being able to add the indexes in the table of contents (as with imakeid)
6. Columns: being able to split the contents of an index into 1 to 3 columns (as with imakeid)

Comment: Point 2: I've just found out that imakeid is not limited to 5 indexes